# Control search Nominatim in OpenLayers: change properties

Tags: openlayers, nominatim, search

I'm using the example http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/search/map.control.searchnominatim.html
to search with Nominatim.

How can I configure the control to perform the search in
a single country and city, for example?

```
// Set the search control 
var searchNominatim = new ol.control.SearchNominatim (
    {   //target: $(".options").get(0),
    //  polygon: $("#polygon").prop("checked"),
        reverse: true,
        position: true, // Search, with priority to geo position
        title: "Busca",
        reverseTitle: "Clique no mapa...",
        placeholder: "Busca..."
    });
map.addControl (searchNominatim);

// Select feature when click on the reference index
searchNominatim.on('select', function(e)
{   
//  sLayer.getSource().clear();
    // Check if we get a geojson to describe the search
    if (e.search.geojson) {
        var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
        var f = format.readFeature(e.search.geojson, { dataProjection: "EPSG:4326", featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection() });
    //  sLayer.getSource().addFeature(f);
        var view = map.getView();
        var resolution = view.getResolutionForExtent(f.getGeometry().getExtent(), map.getSize());
        var zoom = view.getZoomForResolution(resolution);
        var center = ol.extent.getCenter(f.getGeometry().getExtent());
        // redraw before zoom
        setTimeout(function(){
                view.animate({
                center: center,
                zoom: Math.min (zoom, 16)
            });
        }, 100);
    }
    else {
        map.getView().animate({
            center:e.coordinate,
            zoom: Math.max (map.getView().getZoom(),16)
        });
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you would need to patch the `requestData` function to add `countrycodes` to the request. e.g. to restrict results to UK and Ireland

```
var searchNominatim = new ol.control.SearchNominatim (
    {   //target: $(".options").get(0),
    //  polygon: $("#polygon").prop("checked"),
        reverse: true,
        position: true, // Search, with priority to geo position
        title: "Busca",
        reverseTitle: "Clique no mapa...",
        placeholder: "Busca..."
    });
var requestData = searchNominatim.requestData.bind(searchNominatim);
searchNominatim.requestData = function (s) {
    var data = requestData(s);
    data.countrycodes = 'gb,ie';
    return data;
};
map.addControl (searchNominatim);
```

It might be better to raise an issue with ol-ext to add `countrycodes`  as a supported option.

Comment: Thanks for the tipo, but I couldn't filter by city.